# how to build GNU Classpath and JamVM

Tags: classpath, gnu, jamvm

I'm trying to build GNU Classpath 0.98 and JamVM 1.5.2.
Following the JamVM readme, I did 'configure; make; make install' on the jamVM, and it worked.

I then added jamvm and Sun javac to the path.
Then with GNU Classpath I did this:

```
./configure --enable-jni --disable-gtk-peer --disable-gconf-peer --disable-plugin
```

I got this error:

> The javac failed (see config.log)

On the `config.log`, I see that javac can't find VMStackWalker (which is jamvm-specific)
I added the jamvm classes to the CLASSPATH, then I got this error:

> The Java VM jamvm failed (see config.log)

On the `config.log`, I see that jamvm cannot find `java.lang.Class`.

What's wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fount it!

http://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=7193290

Comment: Yes, as this is the solution for the problem, and no one else has found it.

Comment: That said, this breaks the rules for link-only answers on StackOverflow: An answer should copy in enough information from behind any links it uses to still remain useful even if that link breaks. See also the "provide context for links" section in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: (indeed, reading that thread, I have no idea *which* of the answers proposed, and by which person in the discussion, is the one that solved your problem)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to compiling GNU Classpath for Ubuntu12.04:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jruby-gsoc/-fnKnP7zxbI

Steps to compiling JamVM for Ubuntu 12.04:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jruby-gsoc/uJ6RlVvHR-0

Answer (score 0):

try ecj,classpath need a java compiler ,and sun sdk seems to be no good here

Answer (score 0):

My Mac OS X 10.11 adventures:

### JamVM

[built with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940503/building-jamvm-1-5-4-on-os-x-lion) `make clean && CFLAGS="-m32" ./configure`.

### GNU Classpath

took a bit more:

```
# If you already made an attempt
make clean

## If you don't --disable-tools. I didn't have antlr, so I downloaded it.
#curl -O http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar

./configure --disable-gtk-peer --disable-gconf-peer \
    --disable-tools # for tools: --with-antlr-jar=antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar
```

If you `make` now, compilation fails with 
`java_io_VMConsole.c:80:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'IUCLC'`. I ended up [googling what that symbol is](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=IUCLC) - it's an octal 01000, and added it right to the source:

```
vim ./native/jni/java-io/java_io_VMConsole.c
# add this line in the beginning of the file: #define IUCLC   0001000
```

After that, ./configure keeps complaining about your `javac` not being GCJ. It looks like an old bug of GNU Classpath, I've found mentions of similar problems. As you see below, `./configure` is broken and won't work with any `javac` other than `gcj`.

I ended up just editing `./configure`:

- in the beginning, I added a line `export JAVAC=$(which javac)`
- I replaced conditional assignment with `JAVAC_IS_GCJ=no`

Now, `./configure` should pass, but `make` won't.

I grepped all the `Makefiles` that `./configure` generated for `-fsource=`, and then either commented out lines with `-fsource` (it's a gcj-specific flag) if there was an alternate lines with `-source` argument, or just replaced `fsource` with `source`.

Last step, I had to edit top-level `Makefile` and delete `$(EXAMPLESDIR)` from `SUBDIRS = ...` line - it didn't compile with an error:

```
./gnu/classpath/examples/CORBA/NamingService/Demo.java:99: error: 
    package gnu.classpath.tools.tnameserv does not exist
      gnu.classpath.tools.tnameserv.Main.main(args);"
```

### It built!

I got errors running it, but [that's a totally different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776571/error-dlopen-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found)...

```
$ DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/classpath/lib/classpath \
  /usr/local/jamvm/bin/jamvm -verbose:class -verbose:jni Test
...
Failed to open library /usr/local/classpath/lib/classpath/libjavanio:
dlopen(/usr/local/classpath/lib/classpath/libjavanio.so, 
1): image not found]
...
Exception occurred while printing exception (java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError)...
Original exception was java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError
```

(I'll update the answer if I manage to run it)