# Failed to render instance of Swifty Button: dlopen(SwiftyButton.framework, 1): Library not loaded

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I just added a pod called "[SwiftyButton](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyButton)" into my Podfile and `pod install`. Then I added both "PureLayout" and "SwiftyButton" into the "Linked Framework and Libraries" thingy.

In the storyboard, I changed a `UIButton`'s class to "SwiftyButton" and this error pops up:

> Failed to render instance of Swifty Button: dlopen(SwiftyButton.framework, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/PureLayout.frameowrk/PureLayout Referenced from: SwiftyButton.framework Reasom: image not found.

I have searched a lot of stack overflow posts and I tried a lot of the solutions, including

- setting the Runpath search path in Build Settings
- removing the frameworks from the Linked Frameworks and libraries
- cleaning the project
- `pod install`

But they all didn't work. The error is still there!

I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776571/error-dlopen-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found) but I have no idea what the answer is talking about. It seems not related to Cocoapods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling the prerelease version of cocoapods.

First, I ran this command:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then it prompted me to choose a version of the gem to uninstall, so I chose 2, which is the prerelease version.

After that I checked the version of cocoapods to see whether it is the newest stable version:

```
pod --version
```

and it is! (0.39.0)

And then I navigated back to the project directory and did:

```
pod update
```

Finally, I opened Xcode and it seems to be working!